# R Add column with count of occurrences of several substrings in all columns

Tags: r, substring

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df<-data.frame(x = c("T302928", "C0293", "G402928", "T30294", "S40298"),
               y = c("B40292", "I980", "B40928", "C203948", "V308283"),
               z = c("C0255", "V302939", "N02938", "R09282", "B02938"))
```

and need to create a column that counts up how many times certain substrings start a value in each column across each row to end up with a df like this.  So for example, if I was searching for values that start with the characters "T30", "C02" and "V30", I would result in a df like this:

```
       x       y       z count_all
1 T302928  B40292   C0255         2
2   C0293    I980 V302939         2
3 G402928  B40928  N02938         0
4  T30294 C203948  R09282         1
5  S40298 V308283  B02938         1
```

The closest I've gotten is something like this:

`df$count_all <- apply(df, 1, function(x) length(which(x %in% c("T03", "C02", "V30"))))`

But I can't figure out how to search for several substrings inside a which() function.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%in%` doesn't do substring matches (that's a python thing).

You can use `grepl`.

```r
rowSums(sapply(df, grepl, pattern = "^(T30|C02|V30)"))
# [1] 2 2 0 1 1
```

If all patterns are all 3-strings, though, one could do:

```r
apply(df, 1, function(x) length(which(substring(x, 1, 3) %in% c("T30", "C02", "V30"))))
# [1] 2 2 0 1 1
```

While it works a bit like `sapply`, I tend to be careful using `apply` on frames since it converts the whole thing to a `matrix` before operations. This can have consequences, most notably that it can be more expensive (with much larger data). `sapply` (and `lapply`), on the other hand, work column-wise, which is a lot less work. With this operation, `sapply` will return a `matrix` of `logical`, which we can then use `rowSums` on to provide the row-counts you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you!  Both options work and are very straightforward.  Thanks as well for your explanation - very helpful in my continual learning about R.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below code with `across`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ sum(trimws(str_extract(.x,'^\\w{1,1}\\d{2,2}')) %in% var), .names = 'new_{col}'),
         count=rowSums(across(starts_with('new')))) %>% select(-c(starts_with('new')))
```

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 4
# Rowwise: 
  x       y       z       count
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>
1 T302928 B40292  C0255       2
2 C0293   I980    V302939     2
3 G402928 B40928  N02938      0
4 T30294  C203948 R09282      1
5 S40298  V308283 B02938      1
```